# How to remove ButterKnife binding for Android views from my code?

Tags: android, data-binding, butterknife

I am looking for a simple way to remove butterknife from code examples.

I found this plugin for Android Studio : RemoveButterKnife

https://github.com/u3shadow/RemoveButterKnife

It's very easy to use and make the job. But is there another way to simply switch to normal Android views declaration ?

Where is the gain between :

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.txt);
```

and

```
@BindView(R.id.txt) TextView txt;
```

Comment: I think the gain is removal of boiler plate Code. But to answer your question, I think, if there's any easier way, he wouldn't create that plugin.

Comment: Yes you are right. My problem was to convert some examples codes. But the plugin make the job (sometimes I have to make some modifications). Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe If you could point out those modifications you encounter, It would help him fix that in later release. Try posting your issue here : https://github.com/u3shadow/RemoveButterKnife/issues

Answer (score 2):

**RemoveButterKnife plugin** :

> ***What's the plugin***
>
> An Android Studio plugin to help remove use of ButterKnife
>
> ***Why I do this***
>
> ButterKnife is a well known open source tool to help you
> inject your view, but some times, you use plugin to generate butterknife's
> code, but you don't want to use it again. It's a very horrible job to
> delete every line inject code and write `findViewById` code, so, I made
> this plugin to do it.
>
> ***How to use it***
>
> 1. Clone the code and build it in your idea
> 2. Then, you can find a jar, install it as a plugin in your AndroidStudio(You also can find the jar in the project)
>
> 3.Open your Activity/Fragment you want to change.
>
> 4.Find the RemoveButterKnife button in your android studio edit menu

**BEFORE :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.hello_world_salute)
TextView helloText;
@BindView(R.id.stock_updates_recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);        
}
```

**AFTER :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView helloText;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    helloText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world_salute);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.stock_updates_recycler_view);
}
```

You can remove redundant casting:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView helloText;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    helloText = findViewById(R.id.hello_world_salute);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.stock_updates_recycler_view);
}
```